# what will happen if two Scanner.nextLine() comes consecutively?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

What will happen if two `Scanner.nextLine()` comes consecutively? Here,the string variable 'pattern' is not storing the second input.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    kmpself test = new kmpself();
    Scanner ab = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text = ab.nextLine();
    String pattern = ab.nextLine();
    System.out.println(pattern);
}
```

Comment: I mean to say string pattern is not saving the input

Comment: Use a single Scanner instance

Comment: tried it but have the same problem

Comment: Very strange - on Windows 10 with java 1.8.0_91 it works without problems (i.e. it prints out the second line that I've entered). What operating system and java version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main (String[] args) {
            kmpself test = new kmpself();
            Scanner ab = new Scanner(System.in);
            String text = ab.nextLine();

            //changing the line of the input solves the problem
            System.out.print("\n");
            String pattern = ab.nextLine();
            System.out.println(pattern);
        }`
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi I do not quiet get your question
Scanner will redirect the input stream to be read according to specific regex, in case of scanner.nextLine() it is the end of line
Read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)
In your case I there is not a problem with 2 scanner instance

Comment: In this case cd in not storing the value  of the second string

Comment: Hi I have tried inside Eclipse and I found no problem. What I do not understand is why do you need 2 scanner? If you read the documentation maybe you can get better understanding of it

Comment: i need two inputs which should be stored in two different variable